# Transform row to column with 2 million records using PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Input Dataframe

| R_ID | C_ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ALL |
| 1 | 2 | BALANCE_13_24_SWITCH |
| 1 | 3 | YES |
| 2 | 1 | ALL |
| 2 | 2 | MATCHING_IC_SWITCH |
| 2 | 3 | YES |

Output Dataframe

| ? | ? |
| --- | --- |
| ALL | BALANCE_13_24_SWITCH |
| ALL | MATCHING_IC_SWITCH |

I would like to fetch 2 million records from the input file and transform row to the column using pivot in PySpark. I have written the code as below. But it's only working if the input file row count is less than 10000, It doesn't work if it's more than 2 million records. Is there any effective way to do the same logic for high-volume data?

```py
df = df.groupBy(col("R_ID")).pivot("C_ID").agg(coalesce(first(col("VALUE"))))
```

Comment: How does it not work, what's the issue you are encountering?

Comment: Its working fine if less records in input dataframe... In case if input data is more than 20 Lakhs.. its taking long time...8 to 9 hrs to complete. I am looking to implement the same logic in efficient way

Comment: What is the distribution of `R_ID` and `C_ID`; are there a lot of duplicate values in there? If so you might need a strategy to partition them in a different way.